# Automatic building eclipse plugins, features and update-sites with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, tycho

**I find best practices for automatic building eclipse plugins, features and update-sites with Maven and IntelliJ Idea (and not PDE)**

I have a project with this architecture (I will not detail files: pom.xml..) 
myproject
----| plugins/
--------| plugin1/
--------| plugin2/
----| features/
-------- feature1/
----| sites/
--------| site1/

I use IntelliJ Idea, and not Eclipse.
I use Maven 3, and not Maven2 or Ant or PDE to build

**Should I use an approach "POM-first" or "MANIFEST-first" ?**

I used Maven and Tycho but Tycho is "MANIFEST-first".
Actually, I use "POM-first" approach. I want to build generating automatically :
- MANIFEST.MF for plugins (plugin1 and plugin2),
- features.xml for features (feature1),
- and category.xml for update-sites (site1)
relative to POM.XML files.

**Is it possible ? Is it a best/good pratice for IntelliJ users ?**

I achieve to generate "MANIFEST.MF" with "maven-bundle-plugin". But I'm stuck on the next... feature, update-site, generating features.xml with the good references (plugin1 and plugin2), generating category.xml with the good reference (feature1)...

**Your opinion ? Advices ? Do otherwise ?**
**How do developers plugins ? How do eclipse community ?**

Comment: Why not use tycho/MANIFEST-first? It works, is easy to use, you work directly using your eclipse/OSGI artifacts.

Comment: Just curious: why would you develop eclipse plugins using IntelliJ? That way you can't just debug, have no (easy) target platform resolution etc.

Comment: I use POM-first because IntelliJ Idea directly manages dependencies Maven in the POM.XML but not in the MANIFEST.MF. IntelliJ Idea is used in my company (by all team members)

Comment: Actually, we work with SVN, ANT, IDEA/ECLIPSE but we want to migrate to work with GIT, MAVEN and IDEA. You know how to set the target platform in the idea ?

Comment: IDEA has some basic OSGI support, but I don't know how good it is. You might be able to make it work, but it sounds like a log of unecessary work.

Comment: This question is not well suited for stackoverflow because it is likely to lead to a discussion. If you want to discuss, you should post this question in a forum suitable for this e.g. the [Tycho mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/tycho-user). If you consider your question to be an architectural question, you should rather ask it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.